# How to iterate a dict/list/dict Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, list, dictionary, boto3

I'm trying to obtain a particular SNS Topic ARN using the Boto3 SDK:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.list_topics

What I want to be able to do is obtain a SNS Topic ARN that I just created using the name somehow.

```
import boto3

sess = boto3.Session(profile_name='sso-account', region_name='us-east-1')

sns_client = sess.client('sns')

sns_client.create_topic(Name='TestTopic_1') # Calling create_topic to create TestTopic_1

listed_topics = sns_client.list_topics() # Calling list_topics and saving as a variable listed_topics
```

What I would like to be able to do is somehow retrieve the arn for the newly created SNS Topic, in this scenario ''TestTopic_1'' the API response is shown below:

```
{
'Topics': [
    {
        'TopicArn': 'string'
    },
],
'NextToken': 'string'
```

}

I'm open to any suggestions, it would have been great if you could plug in (Name='TestTopic_1') in the params but it doesn't work so it seems it's not supported.

Currently what I'm having to do is print listed_topics and go through and find the ARN, I'm hoping there is an easier way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over a list in Python, or how to fetch a particular topic from the boto3 API?  As far as I can tell the data you want (the string `'TestTopic_1'`) isn't in the list the API returns, so iterating over the list isn't of any help.

Comment: Why not just pull out the `"TopicArn"` value from the `create_topic` call itself if you want the ARN of the newly created topic?

Comment: Ahh, well that works... I'm having one of those days I guess. Thanks for the assist!